# WPF used within a WinForms application, where to put Application resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, resources

At present we host a number of *WPF* controls in a *WinForms* application. The application is started using the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(...)` method and *WPF* controls hosted using the `ElementHost`.

In a normal *WPF* application I'd define a `System.Windows.Application` object (`App.xaml`) and call run on it.  Normally any application level *WPF* resources would go in there.  We don't have this.

How can I specify application level resources for the *WPF* controls but still run as a *WinForms* app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a hosted environment you do not have easy access to the Application, Dr WPF has a couple of methods for working in a hosted scenario at http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/.

I am personally using his SharedResources class in a work project, VB6 Form hosting Winforms UserControl hosting ElementHost hosting WPF UserControl with a Application wide theme, for the WPF controls.

Answer (score -2):

If you host WPF controls within a WinForms application you do not have the `Application`object which hosts the application-wide resources. The trick is to create such a object, load your global resources and merge them into the `ResourceDictionary`.

Here is an example of this code:

http://www.snippetsource.net/Snippet/26/load-application-level-resources-in-winforms-hosted-wpf-controls (Link fixed)

Comment: This answer is not helpful; the link to the code goes to a dead page.  Code snippets should be posted *here*.