# Run the MainWindow.Xaml in WindowsForms application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

Is it possible to set MainWindow.Xaml as startup application in WF application(i.e., in Program.cs)? Because in my project, i need to get the current application using Application.Current property.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        //ElementHost ctrlHost = new ElementHost();
        var window = new TestVisualBase.WPF.MainWindow();
        //ctrlHost.Child = window;
        window.Show();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Please let me know, is this possible to get the current application as MainWindow from WF application?

Thanks for reading,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF used within a WinForms application, where to put Application resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191654/wpf-used-within-a-winforms-application-where-to-put-application-resources)

Comment: Hi @Hille, Thanks for your details. In my case, i am using WPF ClassLibrary project. So, i can't use App.Xaml class in WF project as like below code,
public static void Main() {
    WindowsApplication1.App app = new WindowsApplication1.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}

Is there any other ways?

Comment: Of course there is nothing to return from Application.Current if you haven't created an Application class. Why do you need Application.Current?